# Cannot play the sound of music with no error for Java

Tags: java, jlayer

I am trying to run the music that I have, but it does not work. There is no error showing up in the eclipse any more, but the sound is not played. This is my code that I have

```
public class Music extends Thread {
    private Player player;
    private boolean isLoop;
    private File file;
    private FileInputStream fis;
    private BufferedInputStream bis;
    
    public Music(String name, boolean isLoop)
    {
        try {
            this.isLoop = isLoop;
            //Find the link to the file and play, save the file to the buffer
            file = new File(Main.class.getResource("/music/" + name).toURI());
            fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
            player = new Player(bis);
        } catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("No music");
        }
    }
    //Get the time of the music, how long it is played 
    public int getTime() {
        if(player == null)
        {
            return 0;
        }
        return player.getPosition();
    }
    //Stop the music played
    public void close() {
        isLoop = false;
        player.close();
        this.interrupt();
    }
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            player.play();
            do {
                player.play();
                fis = new FileInputStream(file);
                bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
                player = new Player(bis);
            } while(isLoop);
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Also this my setting I have
[image]

Thank you for the help

Comment: Your code works for me, but, I would recommend against extending from `Thread` and instead prefer implementing `Runnable`. I'm also a bit dubious about your `do-while` loop and I need to explore JLayer more

Comment: `file = new File(` <- This is a problem

Answer (score 0):

Your problem starts here -> `file = new File(Main.class.getResource("/music/" + name).toURI());`

An embedded resource can't be reference as a `File`, because, well, it's not.  Instead use `Class#getResourceAsStream` directly.

Next, you should avoid extending from `Thread`, thread's are not re-entrant, that is, once stopped, you can't restart them.  Instead, implement `Runnable`, for example...

```
public class Music implements Runnable {
    private String name;
    private Player player;
    private boolean isLoop;

    private Thread playerThread;

    public Music(String name, boolean isLoop) {
        this.isLoop = isLoop;
        this.name = name;
    }
    //Get the time of the music, how long it is played 

    public int getTime() {
        if (player == null) {
            return 0;
        }
        return player.getPosition();
    }
    //Stop the music played

    public void stop() {
        isLoop = false;
        if (player == null) {
            return;
        }
        player.close();
        playerThread = null;
    }

    public void waitFor() throws InterruptedException {
        if (playerThread == null) {
            return;
        }
        playerThread.join();
    }

    public void play() throws InterruptedException {
        if (playerThread != null) {
            stop();
            waitFor();
        }
        playerThread = new Thread(this);
        playerThread.start();
    }

    protected void playAudio() throws IOException, JavaLayerException {
        try (BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/music/" + name))) {
            player = new Player(bis);
            player.play();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            do {
                System.out.println("Start playing");
                playAudio();
                System.out.println("All done");
            } while (isLoop);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        stop();
    }
}
```

Comment: So what you mention above, that my code is weird, but works? Because I implemented this code to my JFram gui and the sound does not come out in my computer.

Comment: It worked (originally) as a "side effect" from be executed from within my IDE - once exported to a Jar, it will not longer work, as "embedded resources" aren't `File`s